# No module named '_cffi_backend' when running python script using azure.storage.blob.BlockBlobService on Ubuntu in Docker

Tags: python, azure, docker, ubuntu

I have a python3.6 script that needs to get content from a blob storage in Azure which I want to run in a Ubuntu 16.04 docker container.

## The problem

I am using [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/oss-drivers/pyodbc/Dockerfile) dockerfile because I am also using pyodbc to connect to SQL Server. In my requirements file I have listed `azure.storage` which is installed when the docker image is built. But when trying to run the script I get the following error:

```
root@b61c65dadb5d:/app# python3 val.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "val.py", line 12, in <module>
    from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .models import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/models.py", line 27, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.keywrap import(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.constant_time import bytes_eq
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib
ImportError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
```

## What I have tried

I have found a couple suggestions after some searching, one of which suggested to run `pip install cffi`. When trying this I get:

```
root@b61c65dadb5d:/app# pip3 install cffi
Requirement already satisfied: cffi in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from cffi) (2.19)
```

Same goes for `pip install cryptography`

Because python had trouble finding the azure module to begin with I have this at the beginning of my script, so it should be able to find anything located in that directory:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages')
```

(I know I can do this in the Dockerfile, and I will)

Others say that adding `import cffi` in the python script solves the issue. It does not for me.

## How to reproduce

This problem can easily be reproduced with this minimal python script:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages')

from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
```

Then build an image based on Ubuntu 16.04, installing python 3.6, and install azure.storage with pip. Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3.6 \
    python3.6-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-wheel \
    --no-install-recommends && \
    python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    alias python=python3.6

RUN pip3 install azure.storage

COPY /app /app
WORKDIR /app
```

Either run it interactively or add CMD for running the script. Note that the python script must be located in a folder named "app" in the same directory as the Dockerfile.

If you are using interacive you can try `pip3 install cffi` to see that it's already installed.

## Side note

I also want to mention that I have a similar problem when attempting to connect to a service bus on azure. But I will create another question for that spesific problem if I feel the need later.

Comment: @CharlesXu Yes, actually I have solved it, but not by doing what I have in my question. I will make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to make it work using the ubuntu 16.04 image, however, it does work using the python 3.6 image.

As have been pointed out by Peter Pan in his answer the package name was wrong. It should be `azure-storage` not `azure.storage`. Still the problem persisted after changing it to the correct name (it appears that it was still able to get the correct package even with the wrong name). It might be a local issue on my machine, I don't know, I can only speculate at this point.

Anyway, it does work using the python 3.6 image, which is currently based on debian 9, without any problem so that solves the issue for me.

If anyone else is experiencing similar issues while using python to connect to azure blob storage or other azure features as well as azure SQL, here is what I ended up using:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl apt-utils apt-transport-https debconf-utils gcc build-essential

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

COPY /app /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements
CMD ["python", "val.py"]
```

Azure SDK should work out-of-the-box, all the other stuff is for connecting to SQL with ODBC.

Arguably stuff like gcc should not be included in a production image, but that's not really relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is not a package named `azure.storage` in PyPI, which should be [`azure-storage`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage/), so the command `RUN pip3 install azure.storage` is incorrect. Actually, when command `pip install azure.storage` to install Azure Storage SDK for Python, it will also download `azure_storage-0.36.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` to install `azure-storage` package with some issues happened, as the figure below.

[image]

I think the issue shown in the red frame of the picture above would break the progress in a container to next install some required packages for `azure-storage` like `cffi`, `cryptography`, etc. So I suggested you can use the corrent package name `azure-storage` to try again.

Comment: Yes, the correct package name should be `azure-storage` or in fact the recommended one is now `azure-storage-blob`. Strangely enough using `azure.storage` works (at least it does for me...) but the problem stlil persists after changing it to `azure-storage`. Might have something to do with caching. I did solve my problem though, and will create an answer.